# Translate outer() from base R to RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

Is there any way to efficiently translate the outer() function for multiplication of two vectors from R base to RcppArmadillo? I attempted to do so but it is not efficient at all.

Take the following example:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(microbenchmark)

#Outer attempt
cppFunction(depends = "RcppArmadillo",
            ' 
  arma::mat outer_rcpp(arma::vec x, arma::vec y) {
    int x_length = x.n_elem;
    int y_length = y.n_elem;
    arma::mat final(x_length, y_length);
  
    // And use loops instead of outer
    for(int i = 0; i < x_length; i++) {
      final.col(i) = x[i] * y;
    }
  
    return(final);
  }
'
)

#Test for equal results
a <- rnorm(5)

base <- base::outer(a, a)
rcpp <- outer_rcpp(a, a)

all.equal(base, rcpp)

#Test for speed

b <- rnorm(5000)

microbenchmark(base = base::outer(b, b),
               rcpp = outer_rcpp(b, b), times = 10)
```

The results are 2 times slower using R base. I am sure that this can be done though matrix multiplication, any idea how?

Comment: If you look at the base R source code for `outer`, you will see it is calling `tcrossprod` by default which is already compiled code (probably in C in https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/array.c I think). I'm not surprised it is already pretty well optimised.

Comment: Exactly correct, and it likely already goes to BLAS/LAPACK which is ... where (Rcpp)Armadillo sends it too.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to do this more efficiently in RcppArmadillo. The goal of this function is to be nested it with another one also in RcppArmadillo. I know that it is was not the question, but any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @thelatemail pointed out in the comments, the `outer` routine is already using a heavily optimized *C* routine.

- [`src/library/base/R/outer.R`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c499218846d14500255efd622b5021c10ec/src/library/base/R/outer.R#L43): `tcrossprod` usage.
- [`src/main/array.c`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e3f31ad3039eaade6bf9bb0d9201eb13ea33cf66/src/main/array.c#L1138-L1184): underlying *C* routine powering the `tcrossprod` computation.

Armadillo itself has its own optimization for addressing matrix multiplication using the [`dgemm`](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d54/group__double__blas__level3_gaeda3cbd99c8fb834a60a6412878226e1.html) and [`dgemv`](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d15/group__double__blas__level2_gadd421a107a488d524859b4a64c1901a9.html) routines from LAPACK:

- [`armadillo_bits/mul_gemm.hpp`](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/ed593e50a3910ab7396ea7a4e80880bd9ef34e48/inst/include/armadillo_bits/mul_gemm.hpp):  C := alpha*op( A )*op( B ) + beta*C,
- [`armadillo_bits/mul_gemv.hpp`](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/ed593e50a3910ab7396ea7a4e80880bd9ef34e48/inst/include/armadillo_bits/mul_gemv.hpp): y := alpha*A*x + beta*y,   or   y := alpha*A**T*x + beta*y,

Playing around with the outerproduct calculations leads to a few optimizations. Mainly, we're opting to move the outer product into armadillo *actions* instead of loops:

```cpp
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat outer_rcpp(const arma::vec& x, const arma::vec& y) {
    int x_length = x.n_elem;
    int y_length = y.n_elem;
    arma::mat final(x_length, y_length);
  
    // And use loops instead of outer
    for(int i = 0; i < x_length; i++) {
      final.col(i) = x[i] * y;
    }
  
    return final;
  }
  

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat outer_with_armadillo(const arma::vec& x, const arma::vec& y) {
    arma::mat final = x*y.t();
    return final;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat outer_with_armadillo_transposed(const arma::vec& x, const arma::rowvec& y) {
    arma::mat final = x*y;
    return final;
}
```

Revisiting the benchmarking code, we have:

```r
b = rnorm(5000)
b_tranposed = t(b)

bench_results = microbenchmark::microbenchmark(base = base::outer(b, b),
               outer_armadillo_loop = outer_rcpp(b, b),
               outer_armadillo_optimized = outer_with_armadillo(b, b), 
               outer_armadillo_optimized_transposed = outer_with_armadillo_transposed(b, b_tranposed), times = 10)
bench_results
```

| expr | min | lq | mean | median | uq | max | neval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| base | 132.8601 | 141.3532 | 156.9979 | 146.7993 | 154.8954 | 234.2619 | 10 |
| outer_armadillo_loop | 278.4115 | 279.9204 | 317.7907 | 288.4212 | 329.0769 | 451.6872 | 10 |
| outer_armadillo_optimized | 272.4348 | 283.3380 | 347.7913 | 304.1181 | 339.3282 | 728.2264 | 10 |
| outer_armadillo_optimized_transposed | 269.7855 | 270.7108 | 297.9580 | 279.8099 | 312.3488 | 386.4270 | 10 |

From the results, the lowest I could achieve is having a *pre-transposed* `b` vector from column vector form into row-vector form: (n x 1) * (1 x m)